# How to fix "[Dagger/MissingBinding]" in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dagger

I'm trying to inject LatestChart in AppComponent and sloving issue with [Dagger/MissingBinding] LatestChart cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method...
Thanks in advance for your help

LatestChart.kt

```
class LatestChart {

    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context

    @Inject
    lateinit var formatter: YearValueFormatter

    lateinit var chart: LineChart


    init {
        App.appComponent.inject(this)
    }

    fun initChart(chart: LineChart) {
        this.chart = chart

        ***

    }


    fun addEntry(value: Float, date: Float) {
        ***
        }
    }

    private fun createSet(): LineDataSet {
        ***
        }
        return set
    }
}
```

And AppComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, RestModule::class, MvpModule::class, ChartModule::class))
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {

***

    fun inject(chart: LatestChart)
}
```

Compilation error:

```
***AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] sn0w.test.crypto.chart.LatestChart cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: sn0w.test.crypto.di.AppComponent
      sn0w.test.crypto.chart.LatestChart is injected at
          sn0w.test.crypto.activities.ChartActivity.latestChart
      sn0w.test.crypto.activities.ChartActivity is injected at
          sn0w.test.crypto.di.AppComponent.inject(sn0w.test.crypto.activities.ChartActivity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently trying to inject dependencies into the `LatestChart` is how you satisfy the dependencies in objects that won't be created by Dagger (e.g. activities). If you create the `LatestChart` object by yourself (just `val latestCharts = LatestCharts()`), you'll see that `context` and `formatter` are actually injected into this newly created instance.

However if you want Dagger to inject a `LatestChart` object into another (into `ChartActivity` I assume based on the compilation error), you have to let Dagger know how to create its instances. There are 2 ways to achieve that:

**1. Annotate the `LatestChart` constructor with `@Inject`**

```
class LatestChart @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val formatter: YearValueFormatter
) {
    lateinit var chart: LineChart

    fun initChart(chart: LineChart) { ... }
    fun addEntry(value: Float, date: Float) { ... }
    private fun createSet(): LineDataSet { ... }
}
```

**2. Create a provider method in one of Dagger modules**

```
class LatestChart(private val context: Context, private val formatter: YearValueFormatter) {
    lateinit var chart: LineChart

    fun initChart(chart: LineChart) { ... }
    fun addEntry(value: Float, date: Float) { ... }
    private fun createSet(): LineDataSet { ... }
}

@Module
class LatestChartModule {

    @Module
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideLatestChart(context: Context, formatter: YearValueFormatter): LatestChart =
            LatestChart(context, formatter)
    }
}
```